# SumIfs, looking to match part of a string in criteria range with criteria driven from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

```
=SUMIFS('Unspecified Clean URL - Freefor'!B:B,'Unspecified Clean URL - Freefor'!A:A,"*Orlando*")
```

I can manually type in the City Name I am using as criteria, but I have a column of them and was hoping to use that to feed the criteria for all 100 cities, but I am not sure how to get the value in A2 to come through rather than just the cell range I am using since it is in parentheses.

Can someone tell me if/how this is possible?

```
=SUMIFS('Unspecified Clean URL - Freefor'!B:B,'Unspecified Clean URL - Freefor'!A:A,"*A2*")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit] your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array formula, like this:

```
=arrayformula(sumif(Freefor!A2:A, A2:A101, Freefor!B2:B))
```

If you need to match substrings, replace `A2:A101` with `"*" & A2:A101 & "*"`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was possible. I'm too rusty. :)

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)